# Convert minutes to hh:mm:sec in excel

Tags: excel

Can any one help me in converting a minuts cell to mm:hh:sec

Below is the data that that you can see.

[image]

Here I need the highlighed cell data in hh:mm:ss

Awaiting for your response.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `7` in cell E1 means 7 minutes, then you can use a helper calculation with this formula:

`=E1/(60*24)`

Copy down and format the result with custom format `hh:mm:ss`.

Some of the minute values are greater than one day, so you need to decide what to do about these. You could use custom format `d \d\a\y\s  hh:mm:ss` to show the number of days in front of the time value.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Still applicable to date.